# Batch timeout alternative?

Tags: bash, timeout, sleep

What I need is an 80 seconds sleep, that I could skip by hitting a key.
Being able to see the remaining time would be a plus.

Comment: Welcome to U&L, please re-read the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), in particular the part about chit-chat, and please leave out question unrelated material (i.e everything that can be removed without making the question less clear) from future posts.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way would be

```
read -t 80 -n 1 -s -p "Hit a key to continue"
```

You won't get to see the remaining time though. If you want to see the remaining time, you can use a more complex script involving a subshell:

```
( for i in {80..0}; do
    echo Wait for $i seconds or press any key;
    sleep 1;
  done )&
read -t 80 -n 1 -s; kill $!
```

Arguably, the `kill` command is somewhat unsafe, though it's really improbable that the subshell fails to sleep and terminates early, making it possible for an innocent process to reuse its PID and get killed.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple script can be:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=_
count=80
echo "hit a key:"
while [ $count -ge 1 ]
do
    echo -e -n "\rtime remaining: $count"
    read -n 1 -s -t 1 myresponse
    if [ "$myresponse" ]
    then
        echo -e -n "\nyou entered: $myresponse\n"
        break
    fi
    ((count--))
done
if [ $count -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -e -n "\nyou did not entered anything\n"
fi
```

**EDIT**: Added the `IFS` line to change the field seperator to an underscore. Now the script works with whitespace, tab and return key. It is indeed more safe to enclose the test with quotes so I added them.

Comment: in your script, when you hit the spacebar (and that is inside "a key") you skip that iteration, and not the entire "sleep" loop. Otherwise it works as expected. I'm not familiar with the arguments of `read` in bash, though... but the contents of `$myresponse`, when the pressed key is the spacebar, evaluate to false in the `if`

Comment: That's because the script is missing quotes around `$myresponse`: line 9 should read `if [ "$myresponse" ]`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev No, it's not (just tested it, no difference in behaviour). The problem is with the `read` builtin. None of the "white" characters (i.e. tab, space, enter) work in this approach

Comment: @dave_alcarin Yep, that one was less obvious.

Comment: @Lambert I used this in my script, behaves exactly how I need :)
Thanks a lot !